# How do you find a div with a variable class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" id="a1">This is Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="a2">This is Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="a3">This is Link 3</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="somediv">                
</div>

<div class="a1">div 1</div>
<div class="a2">div 2</div>
<div class="a3">div 3</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
    $('#somediv').html($('."this.id"').text());
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Basically what I want to do is, when I click one of the links in the list, it replaces the contents of "somediv" with the contents of a div that has the class that matches the id of the link.

In other words, when I click link id "a1", I want it to display class "a1" in "somediv". I just don't know the syntax for how to call that in the second line of the jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/vD4hA/

Only issue was with your concatination.

You don't need to use `$(this).attr('id')` since `this` inside the context is the DOM element and id or any attribute can be retrieved directly as object properties.

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
    $('#somediv').html($('div.' + this.id).text()); // You probably dont need 'div.' 
   //but it is safe to use as you are not selecting based on id(unique) but a class which      
    //can be in multiple places.
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Do this

```
$("#a1").click(function() {
    var divClass = $(this).attr("id");
    $("#somediv").empty().append($("."+divClass).html());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a').click(function (e) {
    $('#somediv').html($('.' + $(this).attr('id'))).text();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/6544n/)**

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you modify slightly your code to accept the new HTML5 specifications. More specifically, use the [aria-owns](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-owns) which is exactly what you're doing here. See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ApWMB/).

#### HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" id="a1" aria-owns="div1">This is Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="a2" aria-owns="div2">This is Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="a3" aria-owns="div3">This is Link 3</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="somediv">                
</div>

<div style="display:none;">
    <div id="div1">div 1</div>
    <div id="div2">div 2</div>
    <div id="div3">div 3</div>
</div>
```

#### JS

```
$("a[aria-owns]").on("click", function(e) {
   $("#somediv").empty()
       .append($("#" + $(this).attr("aria-owns")).clone());
   return e.preventDefault(), false;
});
```